# multiple sequences in a single variable

Tags: shell, seq

I have two type ranges which I need to get it in a single variable. How can I do that?

eg: I have one range like bs0401 to bs0405 (bs0401,bs0402,bs0403...) and another range like bn0201 to bn0205(bn0201,bn0202,bn0203..) and I need both these expansion under one variable.

I can do for single sequence like

```
h=$(seq -f "bs%02g" 0401 1 0405)
```

but not sure how can Include multiple sequence assigned in a single variable so that echo $h will given like

```
bs0401
bs0402
bs0403
bs0404
bs0405
bn0201
bn0202
bn0203
bn0204
bn0205
```

Comment: Does is have to be in a vairable? You can do it with a for loop like this: `for i in $(seq -f "bs%02g" 0401 1 0405) $(seq -f "bn%02g" 0201 1 0205); do echo $i; done`. I do not need to mention, that you can do anything else instead of echo, right?

Comment: If you assign $h as you write, echo will output values in one line and not each line by line. At least on my computer.

Comment: Or even `h=$(echo bn{0401..0405} bs{0201..0205}) ; echo $h | tr " " "\n"`. Also to get the 4 digits it's `"bs%04g"`

Answer (score 3):

You can include several commands inside a command substitution (`$(...)`). So in your case

```
h=$(seq -f 'bs%04g' 0401 1 0405; seq -f 'bn%04g' 0201 1 0205)
```

gives you

```
$ echo $h
bs0401 bs0402 bs0403 bs0404 bs0405 bn0201 bn0202 bn0203 bn0204 bn0205
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but I'm curious why you didn't upvote the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to store multiple values in a variable, you'd need a shell with array support like `csh`, `ksh`, `rc`, `zsh`, `bash`, `fish`, `yash`.

In `zsh`, `bash`, `yash -o braceexpand` you could do it without relying on a `seq` command here with:

```
list=(bs{0401..0405} bn{0201..0205})
```

Or in `ksh93`:

```
list=(bs{401..405%04d} bn{201..205%04d})
```

Though in this particular case, you could shorten it to:

```
list=({bs04,bn02}0{1..5})
```

Which would work in all 4 shells.

With:

```
string=$(seq -f bs%04g 401 405)
```

You're actually storing into `$string` *one* value which is the output of the `seq` command with the trailing newline characters removed.

You could store the concatenated output of two `seq` commands with:

```
string=$(seq -f bs%04g 401 405; seq -f bn%04g 201 205)
```

Or:

```
string="$(seq -f bs%04g 401 405)
$(seq -f bn%04g 201 205)"
```

Here adding back a newline character between them to compensate for the one removed by the first command substitution.